# Flutter app - QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES automatically adds to build manifest

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I have a flutter android app ,
for some reason

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

is automatically added to build manifest of my app , and because of this google play console is not letting me update my already published app.
I suspect the problem might be in some of the third party pub dev packages we are using.
How to fix this?

Comment: Add the list of packages included.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using linux or unix based os then just go to location where flutter third party packages are installed in my case loaction is
**~/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org**

grep -r QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES *

this will gives all packages pubspec.yaml file path that uses **query all packages permission** remove or replace that packages